# How to we add/remove certain calendars from my app

Tags: ios, calendar, eventkit

I am developing reminder application, I can sync all calendars events which are there in screen -
[image]

My question is it possible to Add/Remove certain calenders? So that I can sync only Added Calenders events.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using swift, you can create a Calendar like this

```
        // Create an Event Store instance
            let eventStore = EKEventStore();

        // Use Event Store to create a new calendar instance
        // Configure its title
            let newCalendar = EKCalendar(forEntityType: .Event, eventStore: eventStore)

        // Probably want to prevent someone from saving a calendar
        // if they don't type in a name...
                    newCalendar.title = "Some Calendar Name"

        // Access list of available sources from the Event Store
                    let sourcesInEventStore = eventStore.sources

        // Filter the available sources and select the "Local" source to assign to the new calendar's
        // source property
                    newCalendar.source = sourcesInEventStore.filter{
                        (source: EKSource) -> Bool in
            source.sourceType.rawValue == EKSourceType.Local.rawValue
        }.first!

        // Save the calendar using the Event Store instance
                    do
                    {
                        try eventStore.saveCalendar(newCalendar, commit: true)

            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(newCalendar.calendarIdentifier, forKey: "EventTrackerPrimaryCalendar")
                    }
                        catch
                        {
                            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Calendar could not save", message: (error as NSError).localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .Alert)

            let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)

            alert.addAction(OKAction)


            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                      }
                }
            }
```

Add an Event to a specific calendar

```
                eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityTypeEvent, completion: {
                    (granted, error) in 

        if (granted) && (error == nil) {
                        println("granted \(granted)")

            println("error \(error)")


            var event:EKEvent = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore) 


            event.title = "Test Title" 

            event.startDate = NSDate() 

            event.endDate = NSDate() 

            event.notes = "This is a note" 

            event.calendar = newCalendar

            eventStore.saveEvent(event, span: EKSpanThisEvent, error: nil) 

            println("Saved Event") 
        }
        })
```

And can get events of a specific Calender

```
        func loadEvents() {
            // Create a date formatter instance to use for converting a string to a date
            let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

    // Create start and end date NSDate instances to build a predicate for which events to select
            let startDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2016-01-01")

    let endDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2016-12-31")


    if let startDate = startDate, endDate = endDate {
                let eventStore = EKEventStore()

        // Use an event store instance to create and properly configure an NSPredicate
                let eventsPredicate = eventStore.predicateForEventsWithStartDate(startDate, endDate: endDate, calendars: [newCalendar])

        // Use the configured NSPredicate to find and return events in the store that match
                self.events = eventStore.eventsMatchingPredicate(eventsPredicate).sort(){
                    (e1: EKEvent, e2: EKEvent) -> Bool in
            return e1.startDate.compare(e2.startDate) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending

        }
            }
        }
```